# Is it possible to stream by rtsp bitmap images?

Tags: c#, networking, bitmap, streaming, rtsp

I'm working on an application C# which consist in collect images (format bayer8) from a camera and then stream it over the local network by rtsp.

I looked for a framework which allow me to send over the network bitmap images.
Every time I find something, it's a file which is streamed, but i need to stream bitmap images.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are proficient enough to use native code (either through COM or P/Invoke), [Live555](http://www.live555.com/) can be used to achieve what you need. I am not aware if it has as C# wrapper (IMHO most likely no). There is also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039651/streaming-using-rtsp-over-tcp) that mentions a [codeproject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp) on RTSP in C# alongside Live555.

That being said I think there is a more important bit of information in your case (which is why I did not simply mark the question as a duplicate). RTP has a predefined set of payload types (so that the clients know how to remux the stream). [RFC4175](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4175) lists the uncompressed video formats for RTP. As far as I understand bayer8 is not just another name for some kind of RGB compression - it is a totally different one (correct me if I'm wrong)? In that case you just can't put your data in a stream that standard clients (VLC, FFmpeg, etc.) will be able to demux. Then it's up to you to understand if you can recompress or if you don't need RTP at all since it will simply not work.